# how to show icon based on condition in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have the following dashboard, which is coded in LWC. I want to show out users who have birthday on this month. But I need to emphasize the person who has birthday today by marking them with a birthday box icon. But I can only put the icon next to all of them, how can I filter to put that icon only to the person who has birthday today. Really need your help, here is my code:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="This Month Birthday" icon-name="custom:custom11">
   <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
      <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small frame" size="">
         <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size=''>
               <div>
                  <lightning-layout class='casedt slds-wrap slds-size_7-of-7'>
                     <template for:each={data} for:item="item">
                        <lightning-layout-item  class="slds-size_1-of-7" key={item.id} >
                                <lightning-tile label='' type="media" variant="Narrow">
                                   <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-5 slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-around_x-medium avatar">
                                         <img src={item.AvatarUrl__c} title={item.Name_And_Birthday__c} class="avt_img">
                                         <lightning-icon icon-name="action:share_thanks" class="BirthdayCheck" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
                                   </div>
                                </lightning-tile>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                     </template>
                  </lightning-layout>
               </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
         </lightning-layout>
      </lightning-layout-item>
   </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
   import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/BirthdayNotiController.getRecords';

  export default class BirthdayNotification extends LightningElement {
   @track data = [];
recordId;
recordPageUrl;
wiredActivities;

@wire(getRecords)
wiredclass({error,data}){
  // this.wiredActivities = value;
  // const { data, error } = value;
  if (data) { 
    // let lstdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("data:" +data);
      this.data = data;
      this.error = undefined;  
  } else if (error) {  
      this.error = error; 
      this.data = undefined;  
  }  
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put something into your data structure that identifies if they're having a birthday today, then you can use that:

```
<lightning-icon if:true={item.birthdayToday} icon-name="action:share_thanks" class="BirthdayCheck" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
```

Which you use by modifying your data:

```
const now = new Date();
const format = (date) => `${date.getMonth()}/${date.getDate()}`;
const today = format(now);

this.data = [...data].map(datum => ({...datum, birthayToday: format(new Date(datum.birthDate)) === today }));
```

This presumes your Apex returns a value that includes a properly formatted Date that you can parse. You may need to change your Apex as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I ask you how can I identify the people having birthday today ? Can I do it by creating a field in Object Setting or by coding ?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh The answer is already in the code.

Comment: @LêQuangAnh It needed an extra pair of parentheses. I sometimes forget those.

Comment: Well, I have tried your code and I also had a test but it seems that the icon still didn't show out for the people who had birthday today :( I can't find the reason, maybe the problem is in my Apex code ?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh Would depend on how your dates are formatted. It could be your Apex, or just how it needs to be parsed. What's the data look like right now?

Comment: I have posted my Apex code in the below comment and my Date_of_birth__c field is currently formatted DD/MM/YYYY, does it affect?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh it should work using new Date(value).

Comment: or maybe I placed the Date format code in the wrong place? I put in after the "if (data) {", is it correct?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh Yes, that should be correct.

Comment: Have you got any clue where I'm wrong in the code? I'm still trying to fix it for a whole day without any progress

Answer (score 0):

@sfdcfox
Here is my Apex code:

```
public with sharing class BirthdayNotiController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static list<FB_Employees__c> getRecords() {
     return [
            SELECT Name, AvatarUrl__c, Date_of_birth__c, Name_And_Birthday__c
            FROM FB_Employees__c
            WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(Date_of_birth__c) = 7
            ];
    }
}
```

But I received this error:
[image]

I don't understand why ?